# Set 100% height minus two other DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YT5vt/

I want the second DIV (div2) height to be always 100%, but minus first DIV and third DIV. And when the browser will be resized only the second DIV will be resized.

Here is the code too

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
<div class="div3">3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.div1{
    width: 100%;
    background: #F00;
    height: 100px;
}
.div2{
    width: 100%;
    background: #FF0;
    height: 100%;
}
.div3{
    width: 100%;
    background: #00F;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: this is called the Holy Grail layout (two fixed-width columns on both sides, fluid-width in the middle). You can Google it.

Comment: height: calc(100% - somepx); try this

Comment: @Doorknob: The Fiddle suggests a fixed header and footer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah, good point, misunderstood the question. The dup you found will work though. (why no close?)

Comment: @Doorknob: My close vote is binding.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but it's definitely a dup, so why not? (also, [status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062/180276) `:(`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the CSS3 `calc()` function:

```
.div2{
    width: 100%;
    background: #FF0;
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 125px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 125px);
    height: calc(100% - 125px);
}
```

However, you might want to use a JS-based fallback if the browser does not recognize the function. `calc()` is supported by approximately 73% of all users - [source](http://caniuse.com/calc).

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/YT5vt/2/

A slightly more complicated JS-based (specifically, jQuery-based) fallback would be:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".div2").height($(window).height() - $(".div1").height() - $(".div3").height()); 
}).resize();

// Resize is fired first when the document is ready,
// and then again when the window is resized
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/YT5vt/5/